# Javascript Performance get

Tags: javascript

If I work with DOM objects it is faster to cache them local (if I want to access them more than once, like in a loop etc.)

```
var myImages = document.images;
```

When I work with classes

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    };
}
```

Is it really faster if I do:

```
var info= apple.getInfo();
```

do something with var Color

or is it ok just to work with `apple.getInfo()` each time?

Isn't info a reference to `apple.getInfo()`?

Comment: For almost all real life purposes there is no difference.

Comment: Try yourself with jsperf.com